# Currency GeoJsonTooltip formatting in Folium

Tags: python, maps, data-visualization, folium, choropleth

I am trying to format GeoJsonTooltip in Folium to display integer number as currency (Thousands separated with comma and 'Kč' string at the end.)
Example:

> INPUT: 1250000
>
> WANTED OUTPUT: 1,250,000 Kč

I cannot do this in Python via string formatting, because GeoJsonTooltip cannot display String tooltips and ends up with following error:

> (TypeError: ufunc 'isnan' not supported for the input types, and the
> inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to
> the casting rule ''safe'')

I have not been able to come up with any solution to this problem.
The code to create the map:

```
map_choropleth = folium.Map(location=[49.724,15.534],tiles='cartodbpositron', zoom_start=8, min_zoom=8, max_zoom=8, zoom_control=False)
choropleth = folium.Choropleth(geo_data = geojson_countries,
                  data = kraj_stats,
                  columns=['NAZEV_NUTS', 'cena_m2_mean'],
                  key_on='properties.NAZEV_NUTS',
                  fill_color='YlGn',
                  fill_opacity=0.7,
                  line_opacity=0.2,
                  legend_name='Cena za m2 v Kč'
                  ).add_to(map_choropleth)

choropleth.geojson.add_child(folium.features.GeoJsonTooltip(
        fields=['NAZEV_NUTS','cena_mean', 'cena_m2_mean'],
        aliases=['Název kraje', 'Průměrná cena', 'Průměrná cena za m2'],
        style=('background-color: grey; color: white;')
        )
)

map_choropleth.save("mymap.html")
```

And this is what i have currently:

[image]

Could anybody help, please?

Comment: Please, provide full code and data. Thanks.

Comment: But this is full code for the map. geojson_countries is just a geojson file with realty prices for each region. I want to display these prices correctly, not as they appear in the attached screenshot.
"Průměrná cena" is the average price and "Průměrná cena za m2" is the average price.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was unable to set currency formatting in CZK, however I was able to set numbers spacing by using localize=True.

```
map_choropleth = folium.Map(location=[49.724,15.534],tiles='cartodbpositron', zoom_start=8, min_zoom=8, max_zoom=8, zoom_control=False)
choropleth = folium.Choropleth(geo_data = geojson_countries,
                  data = merged_areas,
                  columns=['NAZEV_LAU1', 'cena_m2_mean'],
                  key_on='properties.NAZEV_LAU1',
                  fill_color='YlGn',
                  fill_opacity=0.85,
                  line_opacity=0.2,
                  legend_name='Cena za m2 v Kč'
                  ).add_to(map_choropleth)

choropleth.geojson.add_child(folium.features.GeoJsonTooltip(
        fields=['NAZEV_LAU1','cena_mean', 'cena_m2_mean'],
        aliases=['Název okresu', 'Průměrná cena [Kč]', 'Průměrná cena za m2 [Kč]'],
        style=('background-color: grey; color: white;'),
        localize=True
        )
)

map_choropleth.save("mymap_okresy.html")
```